# Django Serializer Model LeftJoin

Tags: django, api, model, left-join

Hi im new to Django and i hope someone can help me with my little problem ^^

i have Models like this:

```
class Article(model.Model):
   name = model.CharField(max_length=100)
   ...

class Stock(model.Model):
   article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
   quantity = model.IntegerField(max_digits=10, default=1)
   quality = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=[(tag.value, tag.value) for tag in States])
   ...
```

and i want to get a list of all Articles with all the Stocks like

```
[{
  name: 'Bla',
  stock: [{
      quantity: 22,
      quality: 'good',
  }]
}]
```

I got a View:

```
class ArticleListView(ListAPIView):
  queryset = Article.objects.all()???
  serializer_class = ArticleStockSerializer
  permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, HasAccess)
```

But im not sure how to use it

and a Serializer like this:

```
class ArticleStockSerializer(ArticleSerializer):
    stock = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_stock(self, obj):

        stock = StockSerializer()
        return stock

    class Meta(ArticleSerializer.Meta):
        model = Article
        fields = ArticleSerializer.Meta.fields + ('stock',)
```

Not working and i cant find the right way to use it.

Hope someone can help me :)

thx and regards

xQp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with [Serializer Nested relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

```
class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ('quantity', 'quality',)


class ArticleStockSerializer(ArticleSerializer):
    stocks = StockSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta(ArticleSerializer.Meta):
        model = Album
        fields = ArticleSerializer.Meta.fields + ('stocks',)
```

Comment: i tryed it but cant get it working, result is the json with missing stocks

Comment: Try adding `related_name='stocks' ` to `article = models.ForeignKey`

Comment: yeah that was the missing part :D thx <3 that documentation is really hard for newbies ^^